# Excel getting closed when clearing a cell formula using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am using below script to start and stop my RTD function. Each function is assigned to separate buttons. using the first script, I will assign value from `A2` to RTD formula. I want the RTD to be stopped sometime to do some other calculation. So using the second button, I am clearing the RTD function from cell `B2:D2`

But the problem, I am facing is, as soon as I use the clear function, excel is getting stopped. Is there any solution for this or a better way to stop it ? ( I can not clear `A2` data, so using `A2` clear instead of `B2:D2` is not possible for now)

```
Sub Symbol_1_Assign()

Dim mw As Worksheet

Set mw = Workbooks("StockScreen.xlsm").Sheets("MW")

mw.Range("B2").Formula = "=RTD(""pi.rtdserver"", ,A2, ""Last"")"
mw.Range("C2").Formula = "=RTD(""pi.rtdserver"", ,A2, ""Volume"")"
mw.Range("D2").Formula = "=RTD(""pi.rtdserver"", ,A2, ""OpenInterest"")"

End Sub
```

clearing function:

```
Sub Symbol_1_Reassign()

Dim mw As Worksheet
Set mw = Workbooks("StockScreen.xlsm").Sheets("MW")

mw.Range("B2:D2").ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: May i know how big is your `Excel` file in terms of size right now?

Comment: @kulapo:       It's less than 75KB

Comment: Try setting calculations to manual before removing the RTD formula.

Comment: @Variatus       Tried it, but no change

Comment: Try to clear the cells successively, one at a time, in a loop. Add `DoEvents` between deletions, or WAIT (to allow time for the server to shut down). If that doesn't help call the RTD function from VBA instead of from the worksheet.